# test a webworks blackberry app

Tags: blackberry, mobile, mobile-website, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-webworks

I have four files (config.xml, index.html, scripts.js, and styles.css). The html has a canvas and a form for users input. I want to run on blackberry simulator (Torch version 6...). I create a zip file of all those files. Then create a bin folder. Now when I run the simulator and load the application, I have either blanc screen, either the following error: Resource does not exist.
Here is the config file code:

BlackberryTest

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. You need to use local:/// prefix before the name of the local resource to access it.